# How to change a Twilio ongoing call "To" field? (using JS/node)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

How do you update an ongoing call to change the "To" field?

I want to be able to forward a call that's been received in a browser client to a 3rd-party webhook. The webhook expects the "To" field to be a phone number I think. The original call has a phone number as the "To" field (eg: "To:+1234567890"). I send it to an appropriate agent and so I believe the "To:" becomes modified to "To: 'client:example'". Then when the call should be forwarded, I use update to send to the 3rd-party webhook, but the 3rd-party expects a phone # in the To field (I think)

The update code is simply:

```
client.calls(req.body.CallSid)
      .update({method: 'POST', url: 'https://voice.example.com/webhook'})
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the call to point to new TwiML, and then forward the call to the new destination as needed.

[How do I modify a call after it has been created?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132247-How-do-I-modify-a-call-after-it-has-been-created-)

Comment: Hi Alan thx for response! I got fwding working using something like below. Do you know how I properly end the parent call (complete?) after this redirect?
To = '+123456789'
client.calls(req.body.CallSid)
  .update({twiml: '<Response><Dial callerId="'+To+'">'+To+'</Dial><Redirect method="POST">https://crm.com/webhook</Redirect></Response>'})

Comment: You still need the Parent Leg, you are directing the Parent Leg to a new child leg (the forwarded destination). The above TwiML will direct the Parent Leg to communicate to the number you are dialing.

Comment: Hi Alan, it seems what I tried earlier is not actually working correctly. How do you create the new Twiml with a phone # as To (when current call has client as To) and redirect the call to a new URL?

Comment: You would use TwiML like this. If callerId is not specified, it uses the callerId of the inbound call. You use the Calls Resource, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource, to update the parent call leg to point to the new TwiML below.

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="+15551112222">
        <Number>+15558675310</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>```